# SOLVED $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/{(p)} \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

in my algebra exam I had to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/{(p)} 
\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}
$ is the subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing only fraction with the denominator which is not divided by $p$, $p$ prime.
Notation: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the field with $p$ elements.

I have not done this exercise, can you give me an help please?

Comment: Are sure you've written this right?

Comment: Now it is correct, sorry.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_p$ meant to be the $p$-adic integers? If not, a better notation would be in order.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{pq + r}{m} \longmapsto r$?

Comment: I think the simplest direct approach is simply to write down the map $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)} \to \mathbf{F}_p$ then prove it has the right kernel. This fact is almost "obvious" if you write out what has to happen to elements in more familiar terms.

Comment: I am afraid that my map does not work, what does you mean with "familiar terms"?

Comment: Ok thank you! I have understood: $\frac{m}{n} \longmapsto mn^{-1}$. It works!

Comment: @user3343783 Rather than adding “SOLVED” to the title, you should supply an answer.

Comment: I have written the map in my last comment. Nevertheless thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume all rings are commutative)

In general, if $\varphi : R \to S$ is any ring homomorphism, and $a \in R$ has the property that $\varphi(a)$ is invertible in $S$, then we also get a homomorphism $\varphi : R[a^{-1}] \to S$ given by $\varphi(x / a^n) = \varphi(x) / \varphi(a^n)$.

You also have the property that $\varphi(x/a^n) = 0$ if and only if $\varphi(x) = 0$.

As a special case, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of an integral domain $R$, then every element of $R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ is invertible after mapping to the residue field $R / \mathfrak{p}$.

Correspondingly, the quotient map extends to a map $R_{\mathfrak{p}} \mapsto R/\mathfrak{p}$, and the kernel is precisely $\mathfrak{p}_{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathfrak{p} R_{\mathfrak{p}}$: the ideal of all elements whose numerator is in $\mathfrak{p}$.

(I think this is true for all rings, not just domains, but my memory is fuzzy on this point)

In your particular example, we are mapping the fraction $x/y$ to the quotient $x/y \pmod{p}$. We can divide by $y$ modulo $p$, because $y$ and $p$ are relatively prime.

Comment: I don't agree with this: "In general, if φ:R→S is any ring homomorphism, and a∈R has the property that φ(a) is invertible in S" but the rest seems correct. Thank you!